# Looking for alternative to this "fly by in" wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Im looking for a jQuery alternative to this plugin:

"upPrev: NYTimes Style "Next Post" Animated Button" 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/upprev-nytimes-style-next-post-jquery-animated-fly-in-button/

Does anyone know if there is a non wordpress version of this? That will work with non worpress sites.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can [fiddle with a working demo of the following code here.](http://jsfiddle.net/695FX/)**

This type of animation is just what jQuery is built to do easily, so I don't think you need a plugin to accomplish this.  Let's say you have a long HTML page with the following `div` that you want to slide out:

```
<div id="botSlide">Hey, look at me!</div>
```

You would style this div to be in a fixed position near the bottom of the page and just off screen to the right, like so:

```
#botSlide {
    padding:20px;
    width:200px;
    position:fixed; bottom:20px; right:-240px;
}
```

The key is to bind the window's scroll event to fire when the scroll bar is past a certain threshold.  Here's one way to accomplish that:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(e) {
    var buffer = 500,
        bsPadding = 40,
        slideIn = ($(this).scrollTop() > 
                  ($('body').height() - $(window).height() - buffer)),
        $bs = $('#botSlide');

    if (slideIn) {
        $bs.not(':animated')
           .stop(true, false)
           .animate({
               'right': 0
           }, 300);
    } else {
        $bs.not(':animated')
           .stop(true, false)
           .animate({
               'right': -$bs.width() - bsPadding
           }, 300);
    }
});
```

The `.not(':animated')` and `.stop(true,false)` are to prevent quirks in the animation when scrolling fast.